# UITableView loses selection after swipe

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a problem with the UITableView selection. If I swipe to show the Delete button, and then I tap somewhere else to cancel it, I loses the current selection.

How can I retain my selection by the Table even having done that, or at least know if the Delete button is being dismissed (so that I can manually re-select it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default swipe to delete behaviour. There isn't any clean ways to retain the selection after you scroll.

It sounds like what you're trying to do is just to remember a cell selection? In that case, you will need to override the swipe gesture and add your own method. You can store this information any way you like.

As an example, you can check out [this project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows how to handle selections.

Comment: Yes I want it to remember a cell row selection. How would I go about overriding the built-in swipe gesture? I could probably use Storyboard to add a new swipe gesture (though I have never tried it before) but would I activate both of them at once with a single swipe?